# Change IIS PreloadEnable to True Globally

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, preload, iis-8.5

I have a vendor application that will uninstall and reinstall an application in IIS. Each time, I will need to reinstate the preload settings through the command below after installation has completed:

```
appcmd set app "<site>/<sub_site>" /preloadEnabled:true
```

This is because the default value for preloadEnabled is "false". However, I am looking at a way to change the default values for "preloadEnabled" to true so that I do not need to always execute the above command. Could anyone advice me how I could do so?

I am using IIS 8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this. I could modify the default value via Configuration Editor under the system.applicationHost/sites path.

Sample command:

```
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites "/[name='<Site>'].applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled:True" /commit:apphost
```

Replace `<site>` accordingly.